# Giving an url, that redirected is a url with spaces, to Jsoup leads to an error. How resolve this?

Tags: java, redirect, uri, jsoup

Hello I have to parse pages wich URI is resolved by server redirect.

Example:

I have http://www.juventus.com/wps/poc?uri=wcm:oid:91da6dbb-4089-49c0-a1df-3a56671b7020 that redirected is http://www.juventus.com/wps/wcm/connect/JUVECOM-IT/news/primavera%20convocati%20villar%20news%2010agosto2013?pragma=no-cache

This is URI of the page that I have to parse. The problem is that redirect URI contains spaces, here's the code.

```
    String url = "http://www.juventus.com/wps/poc?uri=wcm:oid:91da6dbb-4089-49c0-a1df-3a56671b7020";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    Element img = doc.select(".juveShareImage").first();
    String imgurl = img.absUrl("src");
    System.out.println(imgurl);
```

I get this error at the second line:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://www.juventus.com/wps/wcm/connect/JUVECOM-IT/news/primavera convocati villar news 10agosto2013?pragma=no-cache
```

that contains the redirected url, so this means that JSoup gets the correct redirected URI. Is there a way to replace the ' ' with %20 so I can parse with no problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. This is the problem. The only solution I see is to do the redirects manual. I wrote this small recursive method doing this for you. See:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String url = "http://www.juventus.com/wps/poc?uri=wcm:oid:91da6dbb-4089-49c0-a1df-3a56671b7020";

    Document document = manualRedirectHandler(url);

    Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("juveShareImage");

    for (Element element : elements)
    {
        System.out.println(element.attr("src"));
    }

}

private static Document manualRedirectHandler(String url) throws IOException
{
    Response response = Jsoup.connect(url.replaceAll(" ", "%20")).followRedirects(false).execute();
    int status = response.statusCode();

    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
    {
        String redirectUrl = response.header("location");
        System.out.println("Redirect to: " + redirectUrl);
        return manuelRedirectHandler(redirectUrl);
    }

    return Jsoup.parse(response.body());
}
```

This will print you

```
Redirect to: http://www.juventus.com:80/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/DcdJDoAgEATAF00GXFC8-QqVWwMuJLLEGP2-1q3Y8Mwm4Qk77pATzv_L6-KQgx-09FDeWmpEr6nRThCk36hGq1QnbScqwRMbNuXCHsFLyuTgjpVLjOMHyfCBUg!!/
Redirect to: http://www.juventus.com/wps/wcm/connect/JUVECOM-IT/news/primavera convocati villar news 10agosto2013?pragma=no-cache
/resources/images/news/inlined/42d386ef-1443-488d-8f3e-583b1e5eef61.jpg
```

I also added a patch for Jsoup for that:

- https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/354

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Instead**

```
String url = "http://www.juventus.com/wps/wcm/connect/JUVECOM-IT/news/primavera%20convocati%20villar%20news%2010agosto2013";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
        .data("pragma", "no-cache")
        .get();

        Element img = doc.select(".juveShareImage").first();

        String imgurl = img.absUrl("src");
        System.out.println(imgurl);
```