# JSoup not following redirects and not getting all content for some URLs

Tags: java, android, twitter, jsoup

JSoup on Android is not following the redirects and/or not getting all the content, even when I use mobile.twitter.com . I know it is possible I just have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

URLs that's I've tried are

```
https://mobile.twitter.com/BillGates/status/493831856781926402
```

```
https://twitter.com/BillGates/status/493831856781926402
```

```
private Document getWebPage(String url) {
        Document doc = null;        
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Received site: " + doc.html()); // TODO delete this debug line when done
        return doc;
    }
```

Comment: what do you want to accomplish in the end

Comment: find an image in the tweet if it exists

Comment: i suggest not using jsoup for this becasue twittter has theur own api for things like this so i suggest not using this because it will be more work than its worth

Comment: I can't be because apps like HTML Viewer follows the URL and if I use the Twitter APIs I have to worry about quotas. Also other websites such as Instagram also have this same redirect issue.

Comment: Hey check this out it answers your quesitoin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292919/giving-an-url-that-redirected-is-a-url-with-spaces-to-jsoup-leads-to-an-error?rq=1

Comment: No This also didn't work :/

Comment: Have you tried setting the useragent?

Comment: I experimented with a few userAgents and you were correct! Thanks man!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Daniel B said figuring out the correct UserAgent to use to follow the redirects correctly/ get all the content from the URL.

The best UserAgents I've used are below.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2").get();
```